# How to add a mountable engine into a Rails 3.1 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have created a mountable engine into `~/my_engine` folder:

```
rails plugin new my_engine --mountable
```

How do I mount this engine into a Rails 3.1 app, that is at the same directory level (e.g. `~/my_app`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good writeup of the process here:

http://www.builtfromsource.com/2010/12/13/mountable-engines-in-rails-3-1-beta-getting-started/

In short, add this to your main app's `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'my_engine', :path => '../my_engine'
```

And run `bundle install`/`bundle update`. Add this to your main app

```
mount MyEngine::Engine => '/my-engine-url'
```